# plotting seperate graphs for nested "for loop"

Tags: matlab, plot

I need some help with plotting graphs.

My code is:

```matlab
    alpha = 0.5;  
    K_t = 0.7; 
    K_s = 0.1:0.1:0.6;  
    t = 1:1:12;  
    lambda = 0.1:0.1:1.0; 
    for lambda = 1:length(lambda)

      for K_s = 1:length(K_s)
               K_g = (alpha * lambda * (K_t - 0.01)) * t;
               hold on;
               plot(t,K_g)
               xlabel('time');
               ylabel('K_g');
        end
    end
```

I need graphs for

- lambda=0.1,K_s=0.1;
- lambda=0.1,K_s=0.2;
- lambda=0.1,K_s=0.6;
- lambda=0.2,K_s=0.1;
- lambda=0.1,K_s=0.2;
- lambda=0.1,K_s=0.6;
- lambda=0.3,K_s=0.1;
- lambda=0.1,K_s=0.2;
- lambda=0.1,K_s=0.6;

from this code. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: It's not totally clear what the desired output is. If you want plots in separate windows call `figure` to create a new figure before calling `plot`. If you want separate graphs in the same figure look into the `subplot` command

Comment: For a start, you're plotting the same data every loop...

Answer (score 0):

Something is off with your code. You never use K_s. You might want to check your function again just to be sure everything is fine. Here is some started code to do one figure with many plot in it, I hope this helps!

```matlab
    alpha = 0.5;  
    K_t = 0.7; 
    K_s = 0.1:0.1:0.6;  
    t = 1:1:12;  
    lambda = 0.1:0.1:1.0; 

    % create one figure with many plot in it
    figure;
    for l = 1:length(lambda)
      for k = 1:length(K_s)
               % here we do lambda(l) instead of just taking lambda otherwise you will get the same plot everything.
               K_g = (alpha * lambda(l) * (K_t - 0.01)) * t;

               % plot the evaluated function
               plot(t,K_g)
               xlabel('time');
               ylabel('K_g');

               % hold on for the next plot
               hold on;

        end
    end
```